# Why I am getting TypeError on production server where I am trying to save data in the session?

Tags: python, django, apache, pickle, django-sessions

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: django_server_running_on_apache

Django Version: 1.3.3
Python Version: 2.7.3

Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  178.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py" in process_response
  36.                 request.session.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/file.py" in save
  121.                     os.write(output_file_fd, self.encode(session_data))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in encode
  93.         pickled = pickle.dumps(session_dict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

Comment: The TypeError says: expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found. So that's the reason. For more help you'll need to show the code where the error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to store only scalar objects in session. Pickel fails to serialize other objects.